# Bot Framework how to end a conversation using node.js with "endofConversation" activity posted?

Tags: node.js, api, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am developing using directLine API and bot framework using node.js. Currently, I run into a problem. That is when I use "session.endConversation();" to end a conversation in my bot logic, and then a retrieve the conversation activities using directline apis, there isn't any activities related to endConversation being posted.
I was expecting to see some thing like below

```
{...
  {
    "type": "endOfConversation"
    "id": "CSRTC3lGqTA9jTYpAcsy05|0000006",
    "channelId": "directline",
    "conversation": {
                        "id": "CSRTC3lGqTA9jTYpAcsy05"
                    },
    "code": "completedSuccessfully"
   }
  ...
}
```

but the activity is not there. It seem the conversation is still on if I kept on posting to the conversation Id.
I wonder why is this the case?

Comment: Are you using a version >= 3.8.2?  There was an issue fixed recently: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2767

Comment: You are quite right! I was using version v3.7.0 when I saw this problem. After I upgrade to 3.8.2 the problem is resolved! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to Eric Dahlvang! It is a problem exist in version prior to 3.8.2 . After I upgrade bot builder the problem is fixed.
github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2767